# How to shrink, clone an entire Linux disk and boot it?

Tags: linux, boot, dd, disk, bootable

I had an Ubuntu 14.04 running on a 1024 GB disk (disk A), which only used up to 130 GB spaces. I want to clone it to a 256 GB SSD disk ( disk B ). But failed.

I used `gparted` to shrink the partitions on disk A to be only about 180 GB for the preparation for disk B successfully.

**Can you tell me where I was wrong?**

### 1) restore the partition table

I did backup the partition table of disk A.

```
└──╼ $ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=     2048, size=   997376, Id=83, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=   999424, size= 15624192, Id=82
/dev/sda3 : start= 16623616, size=337020928, Id=83
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

#### Tips

`/dev/sda1` for `/boot`, `/dev/sda2` for `swap`, `/dev/sda3` for `/`.

#### Save partition table

`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > partition.table`

Then I tried to restore the partition table to disk B ( `/dev/sdc` in this scenario ).

I replaced `sda` with `sdc` in file `partition.table`. Then it looks like:

```
# partition table of /dev/sdc
unit: sectors

/dev/sdc1 : start=     2048, size=   997376, Id=83, bootable
/dev/sdc2 : start=   999424, size= 15624192, Id=82
/dev/sdc3 : start= 16623616, size=337020928, Id=83
/dev/sdc4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

Then do the restore successfully.

`sudo sfdisk /dev/sdc < partition.table`

### 2) migrating disk partition content

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1`

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdc2`

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/sdc3`

After migration, those partitions on /dev/sdc can be mounted and viewed.

### Failure

But if I plugged the SSD disk (disk B) into my laptop, it would not boot up after some Thinkpad BIOS output. No error came out but a blinking cursor...

I bet the BIOS even did not detect the `/boot` on disk B when doing booting.

Can you help me? Many thanks!

---

### update

Some one suggested me to use `grub-install /dev/sdc` to do the trick.

I searched what `grub-install` is capable -- [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html) Let me try. And I am pretty sure disk A ( had MBR installed ).

---

#### Update

After doing `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1` , insert disk B only, it's still the same blinking cursor. Nothing really after BIOS.

After doing `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/mypartition/boot /dev/sdc` I went to boot it up, only disk B.

But grub console came out . And reported

[image]

---

#### Update

Now it is working!!!

Here's how I did it, on the PC running disk A as OS and the disk B (`/dev/sdc`) as a USB hard drive.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot

sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdc3
```

Then went to the `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I did replaced 2 things in file `grub.cfg`. (remember to give write permission to the file `grub.cfg`)

#### replace `hd1` with `hd0`

#### replace `/dev/sdc3` with `/dev/sda3`

Then save the file. -> Power off computer -> Insert disk B via SATA and take out disk A forever. -> Boot -> See grub error but still boot up

If you met error `Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue`, please check this to solve it. Press any key will boot your system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/191852/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue

```
sudo -i
```

Then, run each command, one-by-one.

```
cd /boot/grub
rm grubenv
grub-editenv grubenv create
grub-editenv grubenv set default=0
grub-editenv grubenv list
update-grub
```

Now go rebooting, it will work!

This is how I shrank my 1024GB disk hard drive and migrated the entire system to a new 256GB SSD disk.

Comment: If you do `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc` then the partition table and the MBR will also be migrated.  You need one or both (GPT for UEFI boot and MBR for BIOS boot) to have the disk boot properly.  One issue is that you're copying disk UUIDs, which make the kernel confused if both disks (copied and copy) are connected at the same time.

Comment: But the thing is that `/dev/sda` is bigger than `/dev/sdc` physically. I guess the disk `sdc` will be full.

Comment: Then you do need to reinstall the bootloader (grub) code alright, the MBR is squeezed between the partition table and the first partition.  I assume your motherboard is not UEFI (i.e. does not have a UEFI menu when it boots), right?  UEFIs are very different (almost all new laptops have UEFI boot).

Comment: Do not forget to create the grub.cfg file for your new OS. grub-install will install the bootloader on the disk and grub-mkconfig will create a config file (grub boot menu) for the new disk.

Comment: im guessing that disk 1 ATA HDD0 Sandisk... Is the disk you want to boot from, and the bios is set to boot from it?

Comment: Check out this great trouble shooting tool. [Super Grub Disk] (http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). This will allow you to boot from a OS even without a valid MBR. That will eliminate the OS as the problem.

Comment: Once you can boot into the cloned OS now all you need to do is to install the boot loader. Rename the /boot/grub directory in the cloned Os. Redo grub-install then grub-mkconfig and verify that the files were created.

Comment: Thank you. It's been solved. You have the closed answer. Thank you. I will mark yours as the right one. :)

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer (which you've done). Some sites have a convention of adding the word "Solved" to the title. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `sfdisk`, but you could accomplish the same thing, partition table AND MBR back up using `dd`.

*This was in my notes and I am not the author...*

Backing up the MBR

The MBR is stored in the the first 512 bytes of the disk. It consist of 3 parts:

- The first 446 bytes contain the boot loader.
- The next 64 bytes contain the partition table (4 entries of 16 bytes each, one entry for each primary partition).
- The last 2 bytes contain an identifier

Clone the MBR as mbr.img:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/mbr_file.img bs=512 count=1
```

Clone partition as pX.img

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/pX.img bs=1024
```

Restore the MBR to new disk

```
dd if=/path/mbr_file.img of=/dev/sdY bs=512
```

Restore Partition to new disk

```
dd if=/path/pX.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1024
```

**OR**

You could use `clonezilla` to make an image of the OS and restore it on a disk that already has the partitions created.

This way you might need to reinstall grub on the new disk

```
grub-install

grub-mkconfig
```

and set your swap partition in the 'new' OS.

```
mkswap

swapon
```

Comment: Do you mean `grub-install /dev/sdc` rather than `grub-install /dev/sdc1` for this instance?

Comment: yes. mount the new disk, cloned OS partition. grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/newDisk_OsPartition/boot/grub /dev/sdc

Comment: Did you see the question updated mins ago? Grub install failed. No valid system. I didn't see the grub OS choosing interface but the error of this photo